# Java Mysql Escape Backslashes for Select

Tags: java, mysql, regex, backslash

There are a lot of questions already regarding escaping backslashes in java. Depending on what i use i can replace either the char sequence or by regex. however this works fine for escaping one or two backslashes. in my case i need to replace each occurence of one \ with 4 .

EDIT: on the below i left out the second slash intentionally to make clear to get from 1 to 4.

```
String s = "X:\Test\test\test"; //to String s = "X:\\\\Test\\\\test\\\\test";
```

so one would think of:

```
s.replace("\\","\\\\\\\\");
```

or by regex:

```
 s.replaceAll("\\\\","\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\");
```

but whatever i do, the resulting String always contains a maximum of 2 decending backslashes \.
I do not get 4 \\ or even more.
Seems like replace function always repeat until only 2 backslashes are left.

Do i really need to concatenate to a new String in order to get 4 backslashes? No way to solve this by replace?

alternatively is there an escape possibility to search for filepaths in mysql? 
my db stores "X:\test\test", to be able to find it i must escape with 4 backslashes:

```
select * from f where filepath like 'X:\\\\test%'
```

anyone ideas?

EDIT: My eclipse did somehow break it, after i restarted it, it prints 4 backslashes as it should. Sorry for the inconveniences.

Comment: Try this `"abc\\abc".replaceAll("\\u005c", "\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\")`

Comment: @Tirath still the same, results in 2 not 4

Comment: am sorry.but I don't understand - `results in 2 not 4`

Comment: each backslash should be replaced by 4 consecutive

Comment: Idk how you got this result. s = s.replace("\\", "\\\\\\\\") returns "X:\\\\Test\\\\test\\\\test" for me in my console window. Which are the printed values (so double the \'s for the java representation of the string)

Comment: `s.replace("\\","\\\\\\\\");` gets what you desired right?

Comment: @gantners I think I understand it now. `abc\abc` to `abc\\\\abc`. But for `abc\abc` - we get compile time error. Are you able to compile `String s = "X:\Test\test\test";` statement in your class?

Comment: i turns out my eclipse somehow crashed, after a restart it did what it should. so it works the way suggested. I already thought i forgot the java basics... thanks everyone!

Comment: @gantners Use `/` instead of \ to store file paths in the DB. It will save you a lot of time.

Comment: @Tirath yes that would be good.., but in this case i have to eat what i got served :(

Answer (score 0):

This seems wrong to me. 
Firstly "String s = "X:\Test\test\test";" will not compile.

Second, Are you sure your counting your slashes correctly?

Consider this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s = "X:\\Test\\test\\test";
    s = s.replace("\\", "\\\\\\\\");
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

This prints the following to console:

```
X:\\\\Test\\\\test\\\\test
```

And if you inspect the variable in an IDE at runtime to get the string with the \'s escaped it comes out as:

```
X:\\\\\\\\Test\\\\\\\\test\\\\\\\\test
```

Maybe youre not setting s = to the result of s.replace() ?

Comment: i updated my question above, of course it wont compile that way, i just wanted to make clear to get from 1 to 4 in the outcome, sorry for confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
"abc\\abc".replaceAll("\\u005c", "\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\");
```

Output

```
abc\\\\abc
```

Also,

```
String s = "asdf\asdf";  //does not compile
```